# How to save a file to external storage in the media directory in 2020?

Tags: java, android, download, storage, external

I have a question.

How can I save a file from network to the external storage of the android device, with
`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)`
being depricated?

My Code:

```
    private void download(Context mContext) throws IOException {
        String requestUrl = "http://someresource/..."
        URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        mContext.getFilesDir();
        URI uri = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toURI();
        Files.copy(in, Paths.get(uri.getPath() + "/_test.mp3"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        in.close();
        System.out.println("finished!");
    }
```

I get the error `W/System.err: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /storage/emulated/0/Music/_test.mp3`

I also read the article https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#java
but I suppose this is meant to be more of a guideline to tamper with existing media files, like searching or editing file tags etc. and not simply saving a file in the media directory.

Update:
My app needs to fulfill two tasks. I want to save an mp3 file to the above mentioned directory and also read files from this directory.

Below Q: Working with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Music";` returns the Music-Folder on the built-in flash memory of the Android device.
In that manner I want to know how to get the Music-Folder on the SD-Card of the Android device (when its plugged in).

Since Q: the above Method returns a directory, which is no longer directly accessible to apps. The tasks I want to fulfil are the same as the ones mentioned above.
As @blackapps supposed, using the MediaStore Class is in Q preferable. But how exactly do I do that?

Comment: You should ask the MediaStore for a suitable uri. Open a stream for that uri and then write bytes to the file.

Comment: MediaStore is in fact only available at Q-Level. Do you know another option?

Comment: No. MediaStore is everywhere. And below Q there was not that deprecation. Where are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, MediaStore is not available at Q-Level only. But how exacly do I get the SD-Card-Music-Folder?

Comment: What do you consider to be the 'SD-Card'? Are you on Q?

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer this question. I consider the SD-Card to be the (micro)SD-card which you can put into your phone.
I realize, that in my initial question I asked about the "external storage", which is not necessarily the SD-Card but can be some kind of virtual device on the "internal storage" of the in built flashmemory of the phone.

Comment: `final Uri externalContentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(externalContentUri);` With a filename provided I may now be able to download my File in the right place. But I want to scan the path where the content style uri leads.

Comment: Repeat: are you on Q?

Comment: I want Q to be supported.

Comment: Your posted code can not work under Q. Your code should be different for Q and below Q. Further if you have errors you should tell if that was under Q or below. You make it pretty hard for us to help you.

Comment: I updated my question to crearify the tasks to be fulfilled.

Comment: Micro SD cards are read only below Q. So if there was a Music folder on it you could not write to it. For nice examples using the MediaStore read stackoverflow pages tagged `mediastore`.

Comment: Thanks for your support, blackapps.
It's possible though to write to Micro-SD cards below Q, when using `File[] filelist = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);` and then get the SD-Card directory in the array above 0. Though only your own app can use the files saved there and those files are deleted, when the app is uninstalled. This is not what I need unfortunately. Is it possible to write to SD Card with MediaStore?

Comment: Yes with MediaStore on Android Q+ (but slso only in special directories) and with Storage Access Framework on 4+ on the whole card.

Answer (score 2):

For android 10 and 11 add this line to your `<application>` element in the android manifest file.
hope it will work:

```
<application
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```